# Can Eclipse's Content-assist be made more flexible?

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, content-assist

In Eclipse the auto complete is very very strict. Is there a way to have it slightly looser? For instance:

```
getData()
setData()
```

I want to type "data", and have the two functions above be found but because both functions have "get" or "set" at the start, it doesn't suggest these functions, I have to type `get` or `getD` to finally be able to get it in the auto complete.

I was wondering if there was a setting to have it include 'any' functions that have the search term within it, not just starts with?

I have tried doing searches on Google, but without knowing the the terms I am only getting people asking for help saying 'its not working'.
I just want to change from "startswith" to "contains"..

Comment: For other reader, this is available with Eclipse 4.17 (2020-09). See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62838383/6309).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Eclipse Neon (4.6)

Now Content Assist is more flexible:

[image: autocomplete]

The feature is described [here](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.6/M5/):

> **Content Assist** now **supports substring patterns**. Enter any part of the desired proposal's text, and Content Assist will find it! For example, completing on selection proposes all results containing selection as a substring.

Comment: Thank you for coming back to such an old post with brand new information. It is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

The [Eclipse Code Recommenders](http://www.eclipse.org/recommenders) project includes [subwords completion](http://eclipse.org/recommenders/manual/#completion-engines) which seems to be exactly what you are looking for.

Keep in mind that with the upcoming 2.1 release (together with Eclipse Luna on the 25th of June, 2014), the subwords completion is no longer activated by default. Go to *Preferences > Code Recommenders > Completions* and activate the *Subwords-Completion Processor*.

Comment: The plugin is now archived and no longer available from the link above. But for an easy setup of this plugin, go to `Install New Software` menu and enter this url: https://repo.eclipse.org/content/shadows/releases.unzip/org/eclipse/recommenders/stable/2.5.4/stable-2.5.4.zip-unzip/ and select only `Code Recommenders for Java Developers` (you may have issues if others are selected).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no preferences setting to enable or change that. There are several ways to tweak the behavior of Content Assist under **Preferences** > **Java** > **Editor** > **Content Assist**, such as enabling "camel caps" matching (eg, typing `gD` will find`getData()`), but I see nothing about sub-string matching. It would be a good feature request, though. Please consider entering it in [Eclipse's Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, and the spell checking in my question.

Comment: Now that I know to search for "Content assist" rather than "autocomplete" I found https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=205190 .. Posted 7 years ago.. :(

Comment: Good find, too bad it is an old, stale request. You should consider adding some comments to see if there is still any interest. Better, you could volunteer to help implement the feature; if you ask for some basic guidance the developers are usually willing to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Even better with [Eclipse 4.17 July 2020](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.17/jdt.php#content-assist-substring-types):

> ### Substring/Subword matches for types

> Content Assist now fully supports both substring and subword matches for types:

[image: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.17/images/substring-types.png]

> Substring matches are always shown and subword matches can be enabled/disabled with the existing `Show subword matches` option on the `Java > Editor > Content Assist` preference page.

Comment: Sounds great.. but I have moved away from Eclipse almost 3 years ago. But it's nice to know it is getting more features that you take for granted in other IDEs

Comment: @WORMSS No problem. This answer will be interesting for other readers then.

Answer (score 0):

as @antoine martin mention.. I manage to incude the Code Recommenders by adding below plugin. Im using Eclipse 4.13. Here is the step

1. Help > Install New Software
2. add below URL and enter

   https://repo.eclipse.org/content/shadows/releases.unzip/org/eclipse/recommenders/stable/2.5.4/stable-2.5.4.zip-unzip/
3. Select

- Eclipse Code Recommenders
- Eclipse Code Recommenders Developer Resource
- Eclipse Code Recommenders Third-Party

4. Accept, Install and restart.